# Can directional particles be used with 見る?

Tags: particles

空に見る: to look at the sky

空へ見る: to look towards the sky

Are these correct or can を見る express the same concept?

Comment: "Look" as in your examples does not so much correspond with 見る as (空を) 向く or (空へ) 顔を向ける.

Answer (score 2):

No, 空に見る and 空へ見る are incorrect.

見る is a transitive verb, which must be used as ～を見る.

If you want to say "to look towards the sky", the translation is 空の方向を見る.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence will be: 空を見る

「方向」means "direction", but you don't need to use it in this case.